# why I can not get input from console javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to finish find the hat game in vanilla js but I can not get input from console either way. When I try to use prompt sync I get "Uncaught Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'" error and "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'prompt-sync" even though npm and node are installed and up-to-date. When I try to use readline method it works but it does not continue even after my input.

[codebyte]

```
const hat = '^';
const hole = 'O';
const fieldCharacter = '░';
const pathCharacter = '*';
let prompt = require('prompt-sync')();




class Field {


constructor(map) {
    this._map = [
        ["*","░","░"],
        ["░","0","░"],
        ["0","^","0"]
    ];
    this._uinput = "";


}

falldown(){
}

printgame(){


    let str = "";


    for (const element of this._map) {
        for (const element2 of element) {
            str += element2;
        }
        console.log(str);
        str = "";

    }
}

 getUserInput(){


     this._uinput = prompt("Where do we move?");


 }

game(){
    let pcursor = this._map[0][0];
    let xaxis = 0;
    let yaxis = 0;
    let counter = 1;


    console.log("Welcome to the hat game! Find the hat using WASD.")


    do{
        this.printgame();
        this.getUserInput();



            if (this._uinput.toLowerCase() === "w"){
                yaxis +=1;
                switch (yaxis) {
                    case yaxis<0:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;
                    case (yaxis)>this._map.length:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;
                }
                if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "0"){
                    console.log("You have fallen in hole");
                    return;
                }else if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "░"){
                    console.log("you can Continue...")
                    this._map[yaxis].splice(xaxis,1,"*");
                    this.printgame();


                }


            }else if (this._uinput.toLowerCase() === "s"){
                yaxis +=1;
                switch (yaxis) {
                    case yaxis<0:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;
                    case (yaxis)>this._map.length:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;


                }

                if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "0"){
                    console.log("You have fallen in hole");
                    return;
                }else if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "░"){
                    this._map[yaxis].splice(xaxis,1,"*");
                    return;

                }


            }
            this._uinput = "";



    }while(this._uinput !== "");





}

}

const gamee = new Field([
    ["*","░","░"],
    ["░","0","░"],
    ["0","^","0"]
]);
gamee.game();
```

[/codebyte]

[codebyte]

```
const hat = '^';
const hole = 'O';
const fieldCharacter = '░';
const pathCharacter = '*';
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });



class Field {


constructor(map) {
    this._map = [
        ["*","░","░"],
        ["░","0","░"],
        ["0","^","0"]
    ];
    this._uinput = "";


}

falldown(){
}

printgame(){


    let str = "";


    for (const element of this._map) {
        for (const element2 of element) {
            str += element2;
        }
        console.log(str);
        str = "";

    }
}

 getUserInput(){
    let uinputt = "";



    readline.question('Who are you?', uinputt => {
        console.log("uinput");
        readline.close();
        readline.close();
        return uinputt
      });

      
 }

game(){
    let pcursor = this._map[0][0];
    let xaxis = 0;
    let yaxis = 0;
    let counter = 1;


    console.log("Welcome to the hat game! Find the hat using WASD.");
    this.printgame();
    let uput = this.getUserInput();


    do{




            if (uput === "w"){
                yaxis +=1;
                switch (yaxis) {
                    case yaxis<0:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;
                    case (yaxis)>this._map.length:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;
                }
                if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "0"){
                    console.log("You have fallen in hole");
                    return;
                }else if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "░"){
                    console.log("you can Continue...")
                    this._map[yaxis].splice(xaxis,1,"*");
                    this.printgame();


                }


            }else if (uput === "s"){
                yaxis +=1;
                switch (yaxis) {
                    case yaxis<0:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;
                    case (yaxis)>this._map.length:
                        console.log("You have fallen out of cliff");
                        return;


                }

                if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "0"){
                    console.log("You have fallen in hole");
                    return;
                }else if (this._map[yaxis][xaxis] === "░"){
                    this._map[yaxis].splice(xaxis,1,"*");
                    return;

                }


            }
            this._uinput = "";



    }while(this._uinput !== "");





}

}
const gamee = new Field([
    ["*","░","░"],
    ["░","0","░"],
    ["0","^","0"]
]);
gamee.game();
```

[/codebyte]

Comment: Have you run `npm install prompt-sync`?

Comment: Please remember that Stackoverflow has pretty clear [markdown syntax](/markdown). I don't know where you copy-pasted this from, but please don't just paste-and-post: edit your post so that it follows the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) including proper formatting (not just using the correct markdown for code, but also removing spurious empty lines, proper intenting, etc. Remember: you're asking folks to read your code. Make that easy for them). Also: if you get an error, don't summarize or paraphrase it: show the actual error in a code formatted block too.

Answer (score 2):

are you run the code from the console:
$node app.js
?
because if you are running it using vscode debug or similar it will never work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31854928)

Comment: I thought this answer was very helpful. Especially b/c I didn't know vscode could be an issue and I am using it for this very problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use prompt sync you first have to install it with npm in your project dir:

```
npm install prompt-sync
```

then you should use it like this:

```
var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
var n = prompt('My input! ');
```

Comment: Don't use `-g`. Nothing should require global installation (not even tools that ussed to, like `create-react-app`: you use `npx` for them)

Comment: I tried that. I have all the node libraries